# Increase space of ZFS pool over iSCSI SAN, online

Tags: linux, zfs, zfsonlinux

I have an iSCSI volume of 96GB on SAN, which has ZFS pool implemented on it. i have resized the size of SAN volume from 96 to 120GB, but the zpool list only shows the old space (96GB). how to achieve the space of 120G or resize zfs pool to utilize or identify 120GB of space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky one... In the past, a rescan of the LUN would work to get the OS to recognize the new device size. My formula used to be:

```
zpool set autoexpand=on vol1
# Then expand SAN or underlying disk array
echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_disk/2\:0\:0\:1/device/rescan
zpool online -e vol1 /dev/sdb
```

The `zpool online -e devicename` used to work, but in newer versions of [zfsonlinux](http://zfsonlinux.org), this action has been [moved from userspace to the module load](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/808) or a zpool export/import. It may not be able to be done online anymore. I reboot half the time or end up having to export/import the pool.

Comment: Worked for me on `0.6.3-2~precise` (expanded LV, set autoexpand, online -e)

Answer (score 2):

The new size is normally taken into account automatically when the `autoexpand` property is set on the pool.

Otherwise, if exporting/importing the pool doesn't help, you can use this command:

```
zpool online -e pool device
```

Comment: But what, if the zpool online -e pool device doesn't work @ jiliagre?