# Grow ZFS pool to use the whole disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, zfs, zfsonlinux

What's the (if there's any) way to grow a zfs pool that only uses a disk partially to use the whole disk?

Background is, zfs is used here on a virtual machine and the Virtual machines disk has been grown from 10G to 150G. The ZFS pool was created on the 10G disk and should now use the whole 150G instead.

```
 ~ $ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0     4G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0     4G  0 part /base-system
xvdb    202:16   0   146G  0 disk
```

the pool uses xvdb but still thinks its size is 10 GB

```
~ $ sudo zpool list
NAME               SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
data_pool  9.94G  3.62G  6.31G    36%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Comment: Is the autoexpand property set? You can check that with `zpool get autoexpand <pool>`.

Comment: the autoexpand flag was set but for some reason it didn't recognise. however, this pointed me into the right direction. `zpool online -e pool device` fixed the problem for me

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/540969/increase-space-of-zfs-pool-over-iscsi-san-online